# Simple equation not returning correct value

Tags: java

The below equation should output twosFloat as 1 but it returns .8 Can anyone spot my error?

```
int weight = 50;
int barWeight = 45;

int weightWithoutBarWeight = weight - barWeight;

int fortyFives = (weightWithoutBarWeight / 2) / 45;
int thirtyFives = ((weightWithoutBarWeight / 2) - (fortyFives * 45)) / 35;
int twentyFives = ((weightWithoutBarWeight / 2) - (fortyFives * 45) - (thirtyFives * 35)) / 25;
int tens = ((weightWithoutBarWeight / 2) - (fortyFives * 45) - (thirtyFives * 35) - (twentyFives * 25)) / 10;
int fives = ((weightWithoutBarWeight / 2) - (fortyFives * 45) - (thirtyFives * 35) - (twentyFives * 25) - (tens * 10)) / 5;
double twosFloat = ((weightWithoutBarWeight / 2) - (fortyFives * 45) - (thirtyFives * 35) - (twentyFives * 25) - (tens * 10) - (fives * 5)) / 2.5;
int twos = (int)twosFloat;

System.out.println(twosFloat);
```

Comment: The error is that you are using integer division.

Comment: Yes, just declare all variables as `double` rather than `int`.

Comment: print out "twos" not "twosFloat".

Comment: printing twos prints 0. I printed twosFloat to see what it was actually returning. I casted (double) on all the integers being calculated in the twosFloat equation and it returned the correct value. Thanks Tunaki and Paul. =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is convert some of your numbers to either float or double for each equation. The symbol "f" converts an integer to a float.

```
int weight = 50;
int barWeight = 45;

int weightWithoutBarWeight = weight - barWeight;

float fortyFives = (weightWithoutBarWeight / 2f) / 45f;
float thirtyFives = ((weightWithoutBarWeight / 2f) - (fortyFives * 45)) / 35f;
float twentyFives = ((weightWithoutBarWeight / 2f) - (fortyFives * 45) - (thirtyFives * 35)) / 25;
float tens = ((weightWithoutBarWeight / 2f) - (fortyFives * 45) - (thirtyFives * 35) - (twentyFives * 25)) / 10f;
float fives = ((weightWithoutBarWeight / 2f) - (fortyFives * 45) - (thirtyFives * 35) - (twentyFives * 25) - (tens * 10)) / 5f;
double twosFloat = ((weightWithoutBarWeight / 2f) - (fortyFives * 45) - (thirtyFives * 35) - (twentyFives * 25) - (tens * 10) - (fives * 5)) / 2.5f;
int twos = (int)twosFloat;

System.out.println(twosFloat);
```

Answer (score 0):

For more clarity - your integer divisions preceding your last double divide are rounding off to the lower integer and dropping the data after the decimal point. While you could convert the ints to double values you could also initialise double variables and format to 2 decimal places as shown below (assume your original code with doubles instead of ints).

System.out.printf("The result is %1.2f", twosFloat);